# Is there a way to check if Laravel schedule is running?

Tags: php, laravel, scheduled-tasks

I am maintaining many copies of one application (built on Laravel) on different hosts, and I am looking for a way to check if Laravel Schedule is actually running for each. Does Laravel offer something for that?

Comment: Well one of the way can test if Schedule is running you can dump anything to log file. Log::info('Schedule Running '. \Carbon\Carbon::now());

After that you can grep the message from Logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is nothing built into the framework that will tell you which hosts are running `schedule:run`. You will have to implement that yourself.

If you have a central system tracking the hosts, then you can make a command which sends a heartbeat ping to your central system, and add that command to the scheduler.

If you have some logic that depends on knowing whether its current host is running a scheduler,
then you can make a scheduled command which writes the current time to a file on the *local* disk (writing to the cache also works if it's not shared between hosts, or the key is unique to the host). Then you simply check whether `($now - $last_write) > $schedule_interval` is true.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and fixed it by using an option in my commands:

```php
class SomeCommand extends Command
{
    protected $signature = 'some:command {--other-option} {--schedule}';

    public function handle()
    {
        if ($this->option('schedule')) {
            // this command is triggered by the schedule
        }
    }
}
```

In your `app/Console/Kernel.php`:

```php
class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * @param \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule $schedule
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command(SomeCommand::class, ['--schedule'])->hourly();
    }

    protected function commands()
    {
        $this->load(__DIR__ . '/Commands');
    }
}
```